# Loop through parent DIVs and select certain children

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to loop through the following HTML structure and select all of the children elements. Once those elements are selected, I would like to apply dynamic style values to them, or set them to variables. My simple JavaScript loop is below the HTML.

```
<div class="module">
    <h2>Heading></h2>
    <p>Paragraph content</p>
    <p>Paragraph content</p>
</div>
<div class="module">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Paragraph content</p>
    <p>Paragraph content</p>
</div>

(function() {
  let x = document.querySelectorAll('.module');
  let p = document.querySelectorAll('p');

  for(i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
  }
}());
```

I have seen some examples that use `this.parentNode.children[i].style.display = 'none';`, but I cannot figure out how it would work in my example.

Suggestions?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the children with the CSS `>` operator:

```
let ps = document.querySelectorAll('.module > p');
ps.forEach(function (p) {
    p.style.display = 'none';
});
```

If you prefer a double loop, or need the sequence number of each `p` within its parent:

```
let modules = document.querySelectorAll('.module');
modules.forEach(function (module) {
    let ps = module.querySelectorAll('p');
    ps.forEach(function (p, i) {
        if (i == 0) { /* do something for first child p */ }
        p.style.display = 'none';
    });
});
```

Comment: Why would you not use `NodeList.prototype.forEach()`?

Comment: As the 'for of' loop is not supported in Internet Explorer, what would be the best supported alternative? Also, which loop would allow for each child element to be selected individually and assigned to a variable? I would like to work with them individually.

Comment: Updated to use `forEach` instead of the ES6 `for..of`.

Comment: Thanks. This works, but I need to have access to each individual element within each parent `.module`. How would one select the first `p` from each parent `.module` when it loops through? For example: `if(p:first-of-type) do this`.

Comment: See addition to answer.